# Sort html table row based on last row in a rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to sort the given below table model based on last row in a rowspan.

[image]

From the image I want to sort the table using "Cumulative hours" value.
Here I have used rowspan=4.

**HTML Code**

```
    <table class="Table Table3" style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th align="center" colspan="14">Month on Month Time Logging Summary </th></tr>
        <tr><th width="15%">Name</th><th></th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th></tr>
        <tr class="trs"><td style="min-width:130px;" class="name_col" rowspan="4"><div><h4> User 1</h4></div></td><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Plan hours</td><td class="r1 ">144.0</td><td class="r1 ">120.0</td><td class="r1 ">152.0</td><td class="r1 ">132.0</td><td class="r1 ">136.0</td><td class="r1 ">136.0</td><td class="r1 ">40.0</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Acutal hours</td><td class="r1 ">137.03</td><td class="r1 ">108.24</td><td class="r1 ">146.44</td><td class="r1 ">116.54</td><td class="r1 ">125.39</td><td class="r1 ">126.13</td><td class="r1 ">40.07</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Excess / Lag</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-6.97</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-11.76</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-5.56</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-15.46</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-10.61</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-9.87</td><td class="r1 ">0.07</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Cumulative hours</td><td class="alert_red2">-6.97</td><td class="alert_red2">-18.73</td><td class="alert_red2">-24.29</td><td class="alert_red2">-39.75</td><td class="alert_red2">-50.36</td><td class="alert_red2">-60.23</td><td class="alert_red2">-60.16</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs"><td style="min-width:130px;" class="name_col" rowspan="4"><div><h4> User 2</h4></div></td><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Plan hours</td><td class="r1 ">144.0</td><td class="r1 ">168.0</td><td class="r1 ">144.0</td><td class="r1 ">152.0</td><td class="r1 ">148.0</td><td class="r1 ">152.0</td><td class="r1 ">48.0</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Acutal hours</td><td class="r1 ">143.28</td><td class="r1 ">168.58</td><td class="r1 ">145.11</td><td class="r1 ">149.29</td><td class="r1 ">144.27</td><td class="r1 ">162.24</td><td class="r1 ">50.22</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Excess / Lag</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-0.72</td><td class="r1 ">0.58</td><td class="r1 ">1.11</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-2.71</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-3.73</td><td class="r1 ">10.24</td><td class="r1 ">2.22</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Cumulative hours</td><td class="alert_red2">-0.72</td><td class="alert_red2">-0.14</td><td>0.97</td><td class="alert_red2">-1.74</td><td class="alert_red2">-5.47</td><td>4.77</td><td>6.99</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs"><td style="min-width:130px;" class="name_col" rowspan="4"><div><h4> User 3</h4></div></td><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Plan hours</td><td class="r1 ">136.0</td><td class="r1 ">164.0</td><td class="r1 ">160.0</td><td class="r1 ">136.0</td><td class="r1 ">168.0</td><td class="r1 ">136.0</td><td class="r1 ">40.0</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Acutal hours</td><td class="r1 ">155.52</td><td class="r1 ">182.32</td><td class="r1 ">179.54</td><td class="r1 ">161.13</td><td class="r1 ">193.57</td><td class="r1 ">160.52</td><td class="r1 ">46.5</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Excess / Lag</td><td class="r1 ">19.52</td><td class="r1 ">18.32</td><td class="r1 ">19.54</td><td class="r1 ">25.13</td><td class="r1 ">25.57</td><td class="r1 ">24.52</td><td class="r1 ">6.5</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Cumulative hours</td><td>19.52</td><td>37.84</td><td>57.38</td><td>82.51</td><td>108.08</td><td>132.6</td><td>139.1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs"><td style="min-width:130px;" class="name_col" rowspan="4"><div><h4> User 4</h4></div></td><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Plan hours</td><td class="r1 ">112.0</td><td class="r1 ">168.0</td><td class="r1 ">176.0</td><td class="r1 ">160.0</td><td class="r1 ">148.0</td><td class="r1 ">152.0</td><td class="r1 ">32.0</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Acutal hours</td><td class="r1 ">130.1</td><td class="r1 ">187.43</td><td class="r1 ">194.3</td><td class="r1 ">174.38</td><td class="r1 ">156.44</td><td class="r1 ">170.37</td><td class="r1 ">38.54</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Excess / Lag</td><td class="r1 ">18.1</td><td class="r1 ">19.43</td><td class="r1 ">18.3</td><td class="r1 ">14.38</td><td class="r1 ">8.44</td><td class="r1 ">18.37</td><td class="r1 ">6.54</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Cumulative hours</td><td>18.1</td><td>37.53</td><td>55.83</td><td>70.21</td><td>78.65</td><td>97.02</td><td>103.56</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs"><td style="min-width:130px;" class="name_col" rowspan="4"><div><h4> User 5</h4></div></td><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Plan hours</td><td class="r1 ">136.0</td><td class="r1 ">164.0</td><td class="r1 ">176.0</td><td class="r1 ">156.0</td><td class="r1 ">148.0</td><td class="r1 ">152.0</td><td class="r1 ">48.0</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Acutal hours</td><td class="r1 ">134.49</td><td class="r1 ">168.07</td><td class="r1 ">189.29</td><td class="r1 ">166.04</td><td class="r1 ">151.5</td><td class="r1 ">165.18</td><td class="r1 ">58.35</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Excess / Lag</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-1.51</td><td class="r1 ">4.07</td><td class="r1 ">13.29</td><td class="r1 ">10.04</td><td class="r1 ">3.5</td><td class="r1 ">13.18</td><td class="r1 ">10.35</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Cumulative hours</td><td class="alert_red2">-1.51</td><td>2.56</td><td>15.85</td><td>25.89</td><td>29.39</td><td>42.57</td><td>52.92</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs"><td style="min-width:130px;" class="name_col" rowspan="4"><div><h4> User 6</h4></div></td><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Plan hours</td><td class="r1 ">144.0</td><td class="r1 ">160.0</td><td class="r1 ">176.0</td><td class="r1 ">160.0</td><td class="r1 ">160.0</td><td class="r1 ">120.0</td><td class="r1 ">48.0</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Acutal hours</td><td class="r1 ">163.42</td><td class="r1 ">205.23</td><td class="r1 ">177.36</td><td class="r1 ">182.23</td><td class="r1 ">212.1</td><td class="r1 ">45.17</td><td class="r1 ">38.11</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Excess / Lag</td><td class="r1 ">19.42</td><td class="r1 ">45.23</td><td class="r1 ">1.36</td><td class="r1 ">22.23</td><td class="r1 ">52.1</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-74.83</td><td class="r1 alert_red">-9.89</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="trs2"><td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;Cumulative hours</td><td>19.42</td><td>64.65</td><td>66.01</td><td>88.24</td><td>140.34</td><td>65.51</td><td>55.62</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know what `rowspan` does?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have showed my sample output with rowspan in the question

Comment: Ok. I think I misunderstood what you wanted `rowspan` to do. I still don't understand how you expect to sort a table "based" on a row. Normally a table is sorted by a column, by comparing the values in each row of that column.

Comment: Might be I missed to explain my problem correctly. My expectation is to sort the current month(July) data based on "Cumulative hours" value, So when sorting the July data, all other months data should align with that column

Answer (score 1):

I thing you need like `datatable` so please check here
https://datatables.net/

Lots of plugin are doing same thing so please check first all plugin if you get some error in these plugin after that raise question.

`rowspan` not use for sorting please check all properties of table.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mpgdggtv/1/

```
//get the Table
var $table = $('table');

//get and cache the groups and the tds in the last Row
//don't have to compute that on each particular click
var $groups = $('.trs', $table).map(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $rows = $this.add($this.nextUntil('.trs'));
    return {
        $rows: $rows,
        $cumulativeHours: $rows.last().children('td')
    };
});


//clickhandler on the header
$table.on('click', 'th', function(){
    //get Clicked column
    var col = $(this).index();

    //fetch for each group of rows the value in the respective column
    $groups.map(function(){
        //create an intermediate value that holds a group of rows and the corresponding value
        //because such caching is way cheaper than computing the value in the sort-function
        return {
            $rows: this.$rows,
            value: parseFloat( this.$cumulativeHours.eq( col ).text() )
        }
    }).sort(function(a, b){     //sort by value
        return a.value - b.value 
    }).each(function(){         //and append the grouped rows in the respective order
        this.$rows.appendTo( $table );
    });
});
```